# SKSpritenode not showing in simlulator or phone when I build app

Tags: swift, xcode

SKspritenode not showing when I build the app in simulator or phone.

I am following a youtube guide on how to create moving background in swift/xcode. My images are not showing when I build. I have tried the following:

- replacing .aspectfill with .resizeFill for scaleMode
- add file extension in imageNamed: "ground.png"
- replacing all images with different ones.
- moving the images to different folder.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ground = SKSpriteNode()



    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

}

    override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

}
    func createGrounds() {
        for i in 0...3 {

            let ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green")
            ground.name = "Ground"
            ground.size = CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)!, height: 250 )
            ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            ground.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * ground.size.width, y: -(self.frame.size.height / 2))

            self.addChild(ground)


        }

        func moveGround() {

            self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Ground", using: ({

            (node, error) in
                node.position.x -= 2

                if node.position.x < -((self.scene?.size.width)!) {

                    node.position.x += (self.scene?.size.width)! * 3

                }
}))
}
}
}
```

Expecting it to create a moving background based on the images loaded.

Comment: See other topics to find out how to post code here.

Comment: sorry, I thought I had. fixed now